# datepicker disabling previous date

Tags: java, android, datepicker

For disabling previous date I am doing the following. The previous dates (from current date) are becoming faded. But I can still select them, which I don't want. Any suggestion what to do? I have read previous posts on this topic but looks like no one faced such issue.

```java
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    return dpd;
}
```

Comment: How are you able to select them? by swiping or tapping?

Comment: I cant go to the previous month(Thats fine). In the current month, previous dates are faded. But I can select them by TAPPING.